# multiple return from php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to get more then 1 value from my php file.

Here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
        alert(response.dummy_code);
        alert(response.user_id);
    },
});
```

and on my insert.php i make this output

```
echo json_encode(array("dummy_code" => "$dummy_code", "user_id" => "$insertet_user_id"));
```

As example `$dummy_code` have to value `5s8374m9f9f3m34mc334` and `$user_id` the value `14`.

With the command

```
alert(response);
```

I get this ouput

```
{"dummy_code":"5s8374m9f9f3m34mc334","user_id":"14"}
```

And the ouput of the two other commands

```
undefined
```

Why `response.dummy_code` & `respone.id` dont work?

Comment: Just for testing purpose: `alert(eval(response.dummy_code));`

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), in particular, the `dataType` option.

Comment: @Hackerman output = undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting the correct content type in the response header? if not tru adding this line before the echo:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("dummy_code" => "$dummy_code", "user_id" => "$insertet_user_id"));
```

Comment: @Name if this helped you, you could mark it as answer. It would help me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're getting a string back you have to [parse the string as JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
function(response){
    var myJSON = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(myJSON.dummy_code);
    console.log(myJSON.user_id);
},
```

If you don't want to do that you can just add a `dataType` to the [jQuery AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
```

[Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: I tried it now multiple times. But the ouput in the console is every time the same, only `{"dummy_code":"5s8374m9f9f3m34mc334","user_id":"14"}`. I think there must be 2 lines more (the value of `dummy_code` & the value of `user_id`)?

Comment: This syntax seems to be working for me just fine. If the last 2 lines were problematic you would get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

your response is not parsed into an object its just a string, if you're returning JSON, tell jQuery and It'll parse it for you.
The are two ways to do it, 1: set the response type to `application/json`

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

or set the dataType in $.ajax to `json`.

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: Yep that was the problem. THanks!